# addSubView of present uiview

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, addsubview

I have created a custom UIView with some labels inside, in other controller.
I have named the UIView "ReportsView.h"

Then back to the main controller UIView, I wish to add a subview inside UIScrollView.
Using the codes below, the view is added, but the content is blank. It is just like adding a pure blank UIView instead of my ready ReportsView.

```
ReportsView *rv = [[ReportsView alloc] init];
[rv setFrame:CGRectMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width,0,self.scrollView.frame.size.width,600)];
[self.scrollView addSubview:rv];
```

Comment: Is it correct that you add it at the `self.scrollView.frame.size.widt` x origin?

And maybe something is "wrong" in your `ReportsView` class

Answer (score 1):

```
CGRectMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width,0,self.scrollView.frame.size.width,600)
```

is being placed just off screen. (or the scrollview is clipping subviews)

I believe the origin of the scrollview's subview should be 0,0 in your case

```
CGRectMake(0,0,self.scrollView.frame.size.width,600)
```

or

```
CGRectMake(0,0,self.scrollView.frame.size.width,self.scrollView.frame.size.height)
```

should work

Comment: Hi Maudicus, it doesn't matter of what size it is. The view simply doesn't appear (it's blank). currently I have to init the viewcontroller with identifier and get its view, instead of init the view directly,eg:
ReportsViewController *sv = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Reports"];
sv.view // the view inside controller